# Python scraping a site with a "SID" encoded URL (without using a webdriver)

Tags: web-scraping

I've looked for similar questions and while there are some, they don't have an answer for this.  I'm trying to scrape the transactions off of Etherscan using a url and requests. The following URL goes to a generic transactions list page from which I'd like to scrape the table. The table is paginated not through the URL, like the rest of the content on Etherscan, but through a javascript method call to our URL, as seen below in the pic; the URL requires an "sid" parameter and if you leave it out, the page sends you to an error.

https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=normal&contractAddress=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&a=&sid=e491732ec95817ef3de11f6f7cb3cdd7&p=1

If the url doesn't work for you, go to any token page and reload and you'll find this url in the network tab.

[image]
[image: elements]
[image]

I've tried looking for other URLs and/or where to get this specific sid so I can generate it somehow and pass it until the URL, but have been unsuccessful; it's not within the cookies or response object and I can't find the id within any of the elements.  If you console.log(window.sid), however, you get the right SID!  So... apparently it's stored as a global/window variable?

[image: console log]

Also, I can put this URL with SID into my browser with the same SID after turning on/off a VPN, using incognito mode, and after resetting my IP and the page will still load. This tells me it must be some sort of time-based session ID related to the server and not a session ID generated with respect to the user, but I'm not sure.

I tried to send a parameter I found (etherscan_cookieconsent), but that didn't do any good either.

Here's the code:

```
    import requests
    from fake_useragent import UserAgent

    url = "https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=normal&contractAddress=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&a=&sid=e491732ec95817ef3de11f6f7cb3cdd7&p=1"

    cookies = {"etherscan_cookieconsent": "True"}
    ua = UserAgent(
        fallback="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36",
    )

    def random_header():
        return {
            "User-Agent": ua.random,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            # "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        }

    resp = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, headers=random_header())
    print(resp.text)
    # this produces some javascript-produced error
```

Ideally, I should be able to get this SID and/or bypass the need for it without having to use Selenium or some other webdriver.

Thanks.

Comment: Etherscan offers a free API. Did you try to use that?

Comment: I did try that, but it's severely rate limited to the point that I can't use it.  Scraping allows me to gather information at scale, several times a day.  I'd have to sign up for several API keys and rotate them to be able to get the breadth of info I need.

The other issue is that the transactions from the API are encoded and don't include some of the detail that their UI does (such as Tags for to/from addresses).